# Passing argument psycopg2

Tags: python, psycopg2

I'm trying passing parameters to SQL query, however, I don't know if I'm making this correct.

```
def getUser(user):
 conn = databaseConnection()
 cur = conn.cursor()
 conn.set_client_encoding('LATIN1')
 rows = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM mk_pessoas WHERE nome_razaosocial= %s",(user))
 rows = cur.fetchall()
 return rows
```

Call this function:

```
row = getUser('brian')
print row
```

Error:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Comment: `(user)` should be `(user,)`. Note the extra comma, since the parameter should be a tuple.

Comment: What if I use cur.execute(SQL,ARG)? How should SQL be written?

Comment: Please answer the question, so I can vote!